# How do I create a grid command in kendo UI that executes and returns an Ajax response which updates the grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, razor-2

I have the following grid in my Razor View.

```
<h2>Exchange Rates</h2>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExchangeRateModel>()
      .Name("exchangeRateGrid")
      .DataSource(builder => builder
                                 .Ajax()
                                 .Model(model =>
                                            {
                                                model.Id(exchangeRate => exchangeRate.ExchangeRateId);
                                                model.Field(exchangeRate => exchangeRate.SourceCurrencyCode);
                                                model.Field(exchangeRate => exchangeRate.DestinationCurrencyCode);
                                                model.Field(exchangeRate => exchangeRate.Rate);
                                            })
                                 .Read("Get", "ExchangeRate")
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
                   {
                       columns.Bound(er => er.SourceCurrencyCode).Title("From");
                       columns.Bound(er => er.DestinationCurrencyCode).Title("To");
                       columns.Bound(er => er.Rate).Title("Rate");
                   })
      .Editable(ed=>ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
      .Sortable()
      .Pageable()
      .ToolBar(tb => tb.Custom().Name("Import exchange rates from ECB").Action("ImportExchangeRates", "ExchangeRate"))
)
```

The grid has a toolbar command which retrieves some exchange rates. These rates should be displayed in the grid once the update is completed. I'm looking for the request to take place using Ajax (this happens). Now the question:

What should I do in the ImportExchangeRates command or elsewhere so that:
1) the page doesn't reload or redirect to a white page
2) the grid gets updated with the values updated by this command.

Currently my command ends with 
    return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
but it's not acceptable as this reloads the whole page.
If I return null the site redirects to an empty page.

I'm sure it's simple but I'm new to both MVC and Kendo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this sample](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/toolbar-template.html) on the Kendo UI Demos.

Basically if you want to emit a custom button or something else that runs some code that does Ajax, you're going to have to dive into some JavaScript most likely.

```
.Toolbar(tb => tb.Template(@<text>
    <button onClick="return importExchangeRates();">Import exchange rates from ECB</button>
</text>);
```

Then in your scripts (client-side):

```
function importExchangeRates() {
    // perform Ajax request here, refresh grid in success handler
    var grid = $("#exchangeRateGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    // return false to prevent button doing silly things with the page in some browsers
    return false;
}
```

I worry that you might be wanting two different data sources for this grid, just from the way you have worded things. If so that will complicate things.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as I can. It's only one datasource for the grid in question, I must have overstated the problem.